# make is not recognized as an internal or external command - Qt SDK - Windows

Tags: windows, qt, makefile, mingw

I installed `Qt` through `Qt-SDK 2010.01`.

How to run `make` on `Qt`'s terminal now?

**I have set the System path:**

[image]

**Qt path command prompt:**

[image]

Please help. :( :(

Comment: @leemes rather `mingw32-make`

Comment: @UmNyobe That did the trick. ***Please put that as an answer so that I can select it.***

Comment: where to write this:mingw32-make
in cmd or cygwin console?  The command is nowhere to be recognized, I added the cigwin's bin folder to path location..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should run `mingw32-make` instead of `make`.

If you want to be able to call it via `make` for simplicity, you might want to define an "alias" which runs `mingw32-make`. While I'm not very familiar with the CMD in windows, I think this should be possible with the following command:

```
set make=mingw32-make
```

However, I don't think this will be permanent. You might want to try to add a batch file `make.bat` in `...\mingw\bin` which runs `mingw32-make` to achieve this. This batch file would however need to "forward" all additional arguments to `mingw32-make`. Maybe there are better ways to create a permanent alias, I don't know.

Maybe you also want to try [the DOSKEY utility program](http://devblog.point2.com/2010/05/14/setup-persistent-aliases-macros-in-windows-command-prompt-cmd-exe-using-doskey/) to create a permanent alias.

Comment: Here's what I do to make a permanent alias: `copy mingw32-make.exe make.exe` in the `mingw\bin` directory.

Comment: @MichaelBurr This is no alias. If `mingw32-make.exe` changes, `make.exe` will not. However, it hardly will change ever, I think.

Comment: @leemes: the comment was half joke. But, it is what I do, and I've found it to be reliable enough.