# LoadError: cannot load such file -- bcrypt_ext on Windows 2008 x64 server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, rubygems

I upgraded my environment from Ruby 2.0.0 to 2.2.3.

I also upgraded (overwrite) DevKit, and re-run ruby dk.rb install.

I removed Gemfile.lock and ran bundle install to start with a brand new environment. Everything looks ok, but I get the error:

```
E:\Projects\development\Stairs>rake db:migrate 
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- bcrypt_ext
E:/Projects/development/Stairs/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
E:/Projects/development/Stairs/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- 2.2/bcrypt_ext
E:/Projects/development/Stairs/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
E:/Projects/development/Stairs/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I first had the same issue with Nokogiri, which I solved using this solution : [Nokogiri load error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28999906/require-cannot-load-such-file-nokogiri-nokogiri-loaderror-when-running)
using Juloi Elixir's solution and installing Nokogiri from a local copy.

But I don't feel like doing this foreach gem! It looks like ruby is searching the gem using a ./ or ./2.2 path, while gems are stored in a ./2.2.0 path. Is this configurable?
How can I solve this issue?

```
Note: Gemfile contains gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.10'
```

Thanks!

Comment: Commenting out bcrypt gem works for running the migration, but I need bcrypt for running the rails application. I don't believe it's a bcrypt issue, probably an install issue I don't understand?

Comment: Devise 4.5.0 and BCrypt 3.1.12 fix this. Uninstall all your bcrypts (`gem uninstall bcrypt`) and run `bundle` again.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Solution was here: [bcrypt-ruby@github](https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby/issues/116):

Rebuild locally the bcrypt gem:

1. Change to the gem directory \Ruby22-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.2.0\gems\bcrypt-3.1.10-x64-mingw32\ext\mri>
2. Run ruby extconf.rb
3. Run make
4. Run make install

Note that this works only if your DevKit environment is correctly setup (run devkitvars.bat).

Comment: I dont get the make command recognized in my shell :( , installed the devkit and did run devkitvars.bat

Comment: For anyone who don't have the `make` command: add `C:\devkit\mingw\bin` to your PATH.

Comment: I added `C:\devkit\mingw\bin` to my PATH, I still couldn't run `make`. For some reason, I had to navigate in `cmd` to `C:\devkit\mingw\bin`, run `devkitvars.bat` and THEN I could run `make`. After I closed the console I lost the ability to `make`. Got the idea from [here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27239491/cannot-install-gem-make-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-o)

Comment: I had to add not only `C:\RailsInstaller\DevKit\mingw\bin` to my PATH, but also `C:\RailsInstaller\DevKit\bin` because `make` and `gcc` (needed to recompile the gem) are located in different folders (?).

Comment: It compiled 6 files until it failed: `c:/devkit2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgmp
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [bcrypt_ext.so] Error 1`

Answer (score 23):

I spent an entire hour fixing this, just now.

Well what I did was I followed some advice online to do a

```
gem install bcrypt --platform=ruby
```

And then, it worked in irb.

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'bcrypt'
=> true
```

Later when I had to do a bundle install, for some odd reason rails installed another bcrypt and the error was back. So I had two folders in my gem root.

```
bcrypt-3.1.10
bcrypt-3.1.10-x64-mingw32
```

So, since the first folder was the one that got built with the devkit, and it works. I deleted the contents of the second folder and copied the contents of the first into it.

Seems to be working as I'm writing this.

Comment: I ran `bundle install` after installing the 'platform=ruby' bcrypt, and it _didn't_ re-install the '-x64-mingw32' version. Maybe a newer `bundler` recognizes an existing version? Anyway you can just start with `gem remove bcrypt` so you don't have to rename directories. Use `gem list bcrypt --local` to list all your versions.

Answer (score 10):

@user1185081 's  solution worked for me in a windows machine. I ran following commands and worked like magic:

```
$ cd C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.2.0\lib\ruby\gems\2.2.0\gems\bcrypt-3.1.10-x86-mingw32\ext\mri  
$ ruby extconf.rb
$ C:\<DevKit Path>\devkitvars.bat  (assuming you have devkit installed)(Ran this instead of running "make" because it was not recognized as an internal or external command)
$ make install
```

Comment: you made my day, after 10 hours of cleaning up and repearing after migration from rasils 2.3 / 1.9   to raisd 5.0/3.2  an other thig that works again

Comment: It compiled 6 files until it failed. `linking shared-object bcrypt_ext.so
c:/devkit2/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgmp
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [bcrypt_ext.so] Error 1`

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me on Windows 7:

1. `gem uninstall bcrypt` to uninstall all versions of bcrypt, including those listed as dependencies
2. `gem install bcrypt` to reinstall
3. `bundle install`

Comment: That just installs the exact same version.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, a designating of the old version to bcrypt in `Gemfile` was a cause of the error. I removed a designating of the version and run `bundle update bcrypt`, then it was settled.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution worked for me:

```
    C:\> gem uninstall brcypt
    C:\> gem install --no-ri --no-rdoc bcrypt
    C:\> cd (path to gems root)\bcrypt-3.1.7-x86-mingw32\ext\mri
    C:\(path to gems root)\bcrypt-3.1.7-x86-mingw32\ext\mri> ruby extconf.rb
    C:\(path to gems root)\bcrypt-3.1.7-x86-mingw32\ext\mri> make
    C:\(path to gems root)\bcrypt-3.1.7-x86-mingw32\ext\mri> make install
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem:

**cannot load such file — bcrypt_ext**

---

Windows 8.1 64bit

ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [i386-mingw32]

Rails 5.1.4

---

**My solution:**

1. gem uninstall bcrypt-ruby
2. gem uninstall bcrypt
3. gem install bcrypt –platform=ruby
4. added this whole line to Gemfile:

gem 'bcrypt', git: 'https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby.git', :require => 'bcrypt'

5. bundle install

Comment: naah. same problem. probably step 4 is whats really solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, add this to your gems file:

```
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7', platform: :ruby
```

Answer (score -1):

This process is for windows:

The problem is with the programs installed on the system.

Uninstall all rails programs:

1. All Ruby programs.
2. RailsInstaller.

Removes all files that have been able to uninstall, you have to do it manually inside:

C:\RailsInstaller

3. Install de ruby version 2.2 from:

http://railsinstaller.org/en

Wait a moment and it's already to go.

MarlonJon.es

Comment: Removing all Ruby and Rails executables is a terrible idea. Some people have multiple Ruby versions, multiple Rails versions, and thousands of gems.