# undefined method `authenticate' for #<User:0x7b7adf0>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new in ruby. I have tried to make a login page. But I am getting this error.

[image]

Here is my coding  -

**users_controller.rb**

```
def login
    @title = 'Login'
    render layout: 'login'
  end
  def create_login
    #user = User.find_by(username: params[:user][:username].downcase).first
    user = User.where("username = ?", params[:user][:username].downcase).first
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:user][:password])
      # Log the user in and redirect to the user's show page.
      log_in @user
      redirect_to @user
    else
      flash[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination' # Not quite right!
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

**router.rb**

```
get    'login'   => 'users#login'
post   'login'   => 'users#create_login'
```

**sessions_helper.rb**

```
def log_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true


  validates :name, length: { minumum:2, maximum: 30 }


  #validates :password, presence: true
  #validates :password, length: { in: 6..20 }
  validates :password, :presence =>true,
                    :length => { :minimum => 6, :maximum => 40 },
                    :confirmation =>true
  #validates_presence_of :password_confirmation, if: :password_changed?


  #validates_uniqueness_of :username
  #validates :email, confirmation: true
  validates :username, :presence => true,
           :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }

  email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, :presence => true,
           :format => { :with => email_regex },
           :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }

  validates :dob, presence: true
  #dob_regex = /\d{2}\-\d{2}\-\d{4}/       
  #validates :dob, :presence => true, :format => { :with => dob_regex }
end
```

Comment: Please post your `user.rb` model.

Comment: @Pavan I am updating my question. Please check `user.rb` model

Comment: Well, you should be having `authenticate` method in `user.rb` model. Are you following any tutorial to make this authenticate logic in your app?

Comment: It looks like you should be including some authentication gem perhaps.

Comment: Yes I am following https://www.railstutorial.org/book/log_in_log_out tutorial. But there are no any authentication. Please check. And let me know how to give authentication in my page.

Comment: You should create your authenticate method. http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial that you're following uses `bcrypt` gem. Check if it is on your `gemfile` and `bundle install`.

For authenticate method follow this tutorial from [railscasts using bcrypt](http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch)

Part of railscast authentication method:

```
def self.authenticate(email, password)
  user = find_by_email(email)
  if user && user.password_hash == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, user.password_salt)
    user
  else
    nil
  end
end
```

Comment: Which line I will adding in the `Gemfile`  this `gem "bcrypt-ruby", :require => "bcrypt"` or `gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'`?

Comment: `gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'`

Comment: But here is mention 1st one  http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch

Comment: Use `gem "bcrypt-ruby", :require => "bcrypt"` as what railscast tutorial did.

Comment: @HashRocket thank you. Let me do this in my project.

Comment: @Chinu, please accept the answer it helps you thanks!

Comment: @HashRocket after adding this line in my Gemfile. I am install bundle then start server in command prompt. But my server not start

Comment: What does the server respond?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108900/discussion-between-chinu-and-hashrocket).

Answer (score 0):

In your `user` model you need to add `has_secure_password`

and

Add `bcrypt (~> 3.1.7)` to `Gemfile` to use `has_secure_password`:

```
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
```

and

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  #your other code
  has_secure_password
end
```

now access the `authenticate` method

[More on it](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html)

on your mention [link of the book](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/log_in_log_out) you refer you can see you missed it.

Go to chapter 6

> > Listing 6.39: The complete implementation for secure passwords. green
> >     app/models/user.rb**

Comment: I am following your code. But i am getting this error message `cannot load such file -- bcrypt_ext`

Comment: https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby/issues/116 this is actual solution..specifically you can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33588735/loaderror-cannot-load-such-file-bcrypt-ext-on-windows-2008-x64-server